# Magento 2 one page checkout - Where to edit authentication popup

Tags: magento2

Where exactly is the code generating this popup on Luma's one page checkout, so I can add a custom HTML block after "Sign In"?

[image: Where]

I tried every place I could think of, but nothing seems to work. The browser console shows that the "Sign In" heading is wrapped inside a "block-customer-login-heading" element. Searching for that element in the Luma template folders brings up the following results:

**/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/authentication.html
/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/template/authentication-popup.html**

I tried editing each of those files in my child theme, using these paths:

**app/design/frontend/My_Vendor/My_Theme/Magento_Customer/frontend/web/template/**
**app/design/frontend/My_Vendor/My_Theme/Magento_Checkout/frontend/web/template/**

(also tried without /frontend, just in case...)

Cleared the cache. No custom block shows.

Is there anywhere else I should be looking or am I just not using the right paths?

Answer (score 0):

This is coming from knockout template in **onepage checkout**.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/cea3e798c145e37f6fb821687dadd0f043352d94/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/onepage.html#L7

You may remove this by overriding

> checkout_index_index.xml

You can look at magento's checkout customization document at below link.

> https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_customize.html

and disable section -

> https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_customize.html#disable